# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException was unhandled by user code and HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid with Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

Recently I'm trying to learn how to use Selenium in Python, but when I try to intialize the Internet Explorer I get a WebDriver exception. The line that raises the exception is this one (and it's pretty much the beginning of the code):

```
driver = webdriver.Ie(r'pathtothefile\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe')
```

(I put the path because I don't know where is the PATH that makes this argument unnecessary haha)

And the error is the following:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException was unhandled by user code
Message: Message: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

As I'm doing this in a corporate network, that might has something to do with some restrictions, I guess...? Or perhaps the fact that I'm using a corporate computer, so they could've taken away some specific actions...? Anyways, Whatever it is the case, what could I do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException was unhandled by user code
.
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
```

...implies that your program was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowsing Session** i.e. **InternetExplorer Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the type of binaries you are using.

To initialize the **Internet Explorer** browser you need to use **IEDriverServer** executable but not *MicrosoftWebDriver.exe* (which is for Edge browser).

---

### Solution

You need to download and unzip the matching **IEDriverServer** from [selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) and pass the *absolute path* of *IEDriverServer* as follows:

- *Windows OS* example:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\IEDriverServer.exe')
  ```
- *Linux OS* and *MAC OS X* example:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path='/path/to/IEDriverServer')
  ```